# Select theme in Revealjs from pandoc

Tags: pandoc, reveal.js

When I run below command to generate slides from markdown, the theme not selected correctly.

```
pandoc slides -o slides.html -s -V theme=beige -t revealjs
```

My slide is in a directory with reveal.js there:

```
|-- reveal.js
|   |-- css
|   |   |-- reveal.min.css
|   |   `-- theme
|   |       |-- beige.css
|   |-- js
|   |   |-- reveal.js
|   |   `-- reveal.min.js
|   `-- lib
|       |-- css
|       |   `-- zenburn.css
|       `-- js
|           |-- classList.js
`-- slides.md
```

But it seems it still not use the theme.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at:

https://gist.github.com/aaronwolen/5017084

The syntax you need is very likely

`--variable theme="beige"`

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to upgrade pandoc from version 1.12 to 1.18

This is the line that I'm using for my transformation:

```
pandoc -t revealjs -s \
       -V theme=beige #specify the theme
       -V revealjs-url=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/3.0.0 \#use a cdn so that I don't need to have it installed
        ./my_slides.md  -o my_slides.html
```

**In order to upgrade pandoc**

Download the latest pandoc version from here: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/latest

Then

```
sudo aptitude purge pandoc #uninstall current pandoc
sudo dpkg -i <name of the file you just downloaded>
```

Comment: Good advice because `reveal.js` url is dead now

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly the syntax is like this:

```
pandoc slides -o slides.html -s -V theme:beige -t revealjs
```

(it might even be case-sensitive if you are on *nix)